# How to change the default serialization/deserialization for Java java.time.OffsetDateTime on Micronaut?

Tags: java, kotlin, jackson, micronaut

I'm using Micronaut v3.8.1. Micronaut is using Jackson for serialization/deserialization, via Gradle dependency management:

```
implementation("io.micronaut.serde:micronaut-serde-jackson")
```

The default serialization for the `java.time.OffsetDateTime` instances is a number that represents the milliseconds since Epoch.

For example, returning instances of a class represented by the next code (Kotlin) from a controller:

```kotlin
import io.micronaut.serde.annotation.Serdeable
import java.time.OffsetDateTime

@Serdeable
class Thing(val created: OffsetDateTime)
```

...a single instance of `Thing` will be serialized to something like:

```json
{
"created": 1674594085000
}
```

I want to change the configuration, to produce the string representation of that date/time, which is:

```json
{
"created": "2023-01-24T21:01:25.191493200Z"
}
```

How to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add @JsonFormat(pattern=)

For example:

```kotlin
@Serdeable
data class Thing(@field:JsonFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSSZ") val created: OffsetDateTime)
```

**UPDATE: Global Setting**

```yaml
micronaut:
  application:
    name: kotlinSerde
  serde:
    write-dates-as-timestamps: false # 1
#    date-format: 'yyyy-MM-dd' #2
```

1. If you want to use default ISO formats instead of timestamps (ex: `"2023-01-30T09:22:01.796846-05:00"` vs `:1675088195756`)
2. If you want to set a specific date format globally.

Note: the `JsonFormat` annotation will be used if declared.

Comment: Thank you, ShingJo. That worked well, it would be great to have a global configuration for that, instead of having to add the annotation to all related fields.

Comment: Updated the answer with example of setting globally.

Comment: ShingJo, the global setting is working perfectly, thank you.

Comment: Can you mark this question as answered? Clears it from my "to-do" list.

Comment: The global setting `micronaut.serde.write-dates-as-timestamps` no longer works and has been replaced. See: https://github.com/micronaut-projects/micronaut-serialization/commit/2072f13677c7d31280f13879c5901fbc8fb38b89